# Hash keys are not able to translate to an array

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, perl-module

I have just this simple code of perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Module::CoreList;
use local::lib;
#print ref( $Module::CoreList::version{5.014002});
@m = sort keys $Module::CoreList::version{5.014002};
```

So that I know some modules of particular version. But when tried to run:

```
Experimental keys on scalar is now forbidden at ./a line 5.
Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash or array (not hash element) at ./a line 5, near "};"
Execution of ./a aborted due to compilation errors.
```

But why does it take `$Module::CoreList::version{5.014002}` as scalar? When the type is hash (well array when you want to know keys of that hash)?

Comment: `ref` told you that the variable is not a hash, it is a reference to a hash. use `keys %{ $Module... }`

Comment: Hashes can only contains scalars. They can't contains hashes. When we say they contain hashes, they really contains references to hashes (references being scalars). `keys` requires a hash, so you need to dereference the reference.

Comment: `ref` told me litterally 'HASH', i dont know wheter uppercase means a reference or just hash as a type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation of `Module::CoreList`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Module-CoreList/lib/Module/CoreList.pod), `%Module::CoreList::version` returns a *a hash of hashes that is keyed on perl version*. So each element of the hash is a hash reference, not a hash.

You need to *dereference* the hash reference, by putting a `%` in front of it, as follows:

```
@m = sort keys %{ $Module::CoreList::version{5.014002} };
```